# Validate yaml schema with golang (semantic check)

Tags: validation, go, schema, yaml, dockerfile

We have tool which need to read YAML file with specific structure. When we got the YAML file we need to know if

> 1. Check if the YAML file is valid according to some guideline - semantic check
> 2. Where is the syntax error if any

For example this is example of the validation that we need to address

```
 _version:  {required: true}
   id: {required: true, pattern: '/^[A-Za_\-\.]+$/'}   
   release-version: {required: true}
   type:   

   builds:
     type:seq
     sequence:
       -type:map
     mapping:
        name:{required: true, unique: true, pattern: '/^[A-Za-z0-3_\-\.]+$/'}
        params: 
          type: map
          mapping: { =: {type: any} }
```

> Mapping is a key value object
>    seq can have multiple builds
>   type any is and key value

We use this open source to parse the yaml https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml

One idea (which is good) is to convert to json like following to do it by converting the file to json and validate it which have library to support it, any example in my context will be very helpful https://github.com/xeipuuv/gojsonschema

But not sure how I handle

```
Type map
Type seq
```

Comment: Why the `docker` tag?

Comment: @BMitch - I believe that docker and k8s have the same task, validate yaml schema for deployment, isn't it ? so maybe I can use the same idea ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is what you could try.

Model a struct after the shape of the expected yaml data:

```
type Config struct {
        Version struct {
                Required bool
        }
        ID struct {
                Required bool
                Pattern string
        }
        ReleaseVersion struct {
                Required bool
        }
        Type interface{}
        Builds struct {
                Type []interface{} `yaml:"type"`
                Sequence struct {
                        Type string
                }
                Mapping struct {
                        Name map[string]interface{}
                        Params struct {
                                Type string `yaml:"type"`
                                Mapping struct {
                                        To map[string]string `yaml:"="`
                                }
                        }
                } `yaml:"mapping"`              
        }
}
```

The yaml flag `yaml:"somefield"` is added to label the field name of the yaml the data we're interested in.

Also many fields with unknown/undetermined type can be declared as empty interface `(interface{})` or if you want to "enforce" that the underlying form is a key-value object you can either declare it as a `map[string]interface{}` or another struct.

We then unmarshal the yaml data into the struct:

```
cfg := Config{}
err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &cfg)
if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error: %v", err)
}
```

Since we have modeled fields as either anonymous structs or maps, we can test if a particular field has a "key-value" value by checking its equality to `nil`.

```
// Mapping is a key value object
if (Mapping != nil) {
        // Mapping is a key-value object, since it's not nil.
}


// type any is and key value
// Mapping.To is declared with map[string]string type
// so if it's not nil we can say there's a map there.
if (Mapping.To != nil) {
        // Mapping.To is a map
}
```

In marshaling/unmarshaling, maps and structs are pretty interchangeable. The benefit of a struct is you can predefine the field's names ahead of time while unmarshaling to a map it won't be clear to you what the keys are.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! few question, it will be great if you can add the answer to your answer :) , 1. is it better to use it like this from using jsonschema i.e. convert to json and validate ? 2. what is the porpuse of all those annotations like `yaml:"type"` `yaml:"="` etc, how it works ? 3. what are those types `interface{}` and `map[string]interface{}` in golang? 4. do you know perhaps what  `k8s` and `docker compose` is doing to resolve this issue , the both have yaml schema that im sure that need to validate ?  Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: It's up to you / your team if you want to convert to JSON. In general JSON is simpler to parse of course. All other questions are added into the answer, except the last one about docker which I have no answer to, and perhaps better be asked in another question.

Comment: Thanks a lot 1+! I've found this https://github.com/docker/libcompose/blob/master/config/schema.go   and this https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/master/compose/config/config_schema_v2.0.json  , what do you think, if you need to do it which way you choose, for simplicity and not getting to dead end?

Comment: I'm sorry but I think this is getting out of the question's scope.

Comment: Thanks, I close the question as answered, my question is if you need to do such of task which way you will go :) ?

Answer (score 3):

You can make `go-yaml` work with `jsonschema`. See this issue: https://github.com/santhosh-tekuri/jsonschema/issues/5

In short:

1. Create a custom yaml parser that produces compatible output types, as per [this issue](https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml/issues/139#issuecomment-220072190).
2. Parse the yaml into an `interface{}` using that custom parser
3. Validate with `jsonschema.ValidateInterface`.

(once yaml.v3 has been released, the custom unmarshaller should be able to be replaced with a configuration option)

I was originally using the accepted answer's approach of parsing into a struct and then writing code to manually validate that the struct met my spec. This quickly got very ugly - the above approach allows for a clean separate spec and reliable validation of it.